# how to use assignment operator in list comprehension

Tags: python, list-comprehension

i want to create a list of random integers

I want the value of num to be a random integer The following line of code gives me a syntax error
invalid syntax

i just want to know that is there any way to do this using list comprehension

```
numbers = [num for num in range(1,6) num = random.randint(1,10)]
```

Answer (score 2):

Looking at your requirements, you aren't required to assign `num`.
To generate a list of random numbers simply do:

```
numbers = [random.randint(1,10) for _ in range(1,6)]
```

You can alternatively do:

```
numbers = random.sample(range(1,11),k=5) # k is the repeating count
```

Comment: Surely k=5 would be closer to OP's requirement

Comment: @Cobra true, didn't give that a look.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the `num` variable, just use the `random.randint()` call.

```
numbers = [random.randint(1,10) for _ in range(1,6)]
```